# GEE data download

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, error, download

I am trying to download alos-2 data from Google Earth Engine as follows.

---

```
var alos2 = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR-2/Level2_2/ScanSAR').select(['HH','HV','LIN']);
var region=ee.Geometry.Rectangle([105.1,10.5,106.1,9.0]);
var point=ee.Geometry.Point([105.6,9.75]);


var dataset = alos2.filterBounds(region).filterDate('2018-10-01','2018-12-31');
//print(dataset);


var imageList = alos2.toList(100)
var image = ee.Image(imageList.get(2));
Export.image.toDrive({image:image,description:'alos2test',scale:25,crs:'EPSG:4326',folder:'gee_mekong',region:region});
```

---

The problem was only a very small size tif file (only 500kb) was saved in the Google drive directory, whose values were broken (i.e., all values were zero when I checked the data from GUI based remote sensing software). I think something is wrong with my GEE code, since file is size supposed to be much greater than this.

---

I tried to use python_gdal to check the pixel values as follows but still all pixel values were zero.

```
FileSource = r'./alos2test.tif'
dataSource = gdal.Open(FileSource)
array = np.array(dataSource.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray()).astype("uint16")

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(array[:,:])
plt.colorbar()
```

---

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Two observations:

1. with `alos2.toList(100)` you are converting the first 100 elements of the whole collection (so the chance to fit with your area is low). Change it to the filtered list (`dataset`)
2. use the scene CRS when exporting the image to drive.

So the code will be:

```
var alos2 = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR-2/Level2_2/ScanSAR').select(['HH','HV','LIN']);
var region=ee.Geometry.Rectangle([105.1,10.5,106.1,9.0]);
var point=ee.Geometry.Point([105.6,9.75]);

var dataset = alos2.filterBounds(region).filterDate('2018-10-01','2018-12-31');

var imageList = dataset.toList(100);
var image = ee.Image(imageList.get(2));
Export.image.toDrive({image:image,description:'alos2test',scale:25,crs:'EPSG:32757',folder:'gee_mekong',region:region});
```

Take a look into [geetools](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki) if you want to export the whole entire collection rather than image-by-image

Comment: Thank you very much for your instructin. ummm. though i revised as you mentioned. it does not work yet. ummm. weird. do you have other suggestion as well?

Comment: hello. I just solved the problem by adding filter at imagecollection part like, var p2 =ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR-2/Level2_2/ScanSAR').filterBounds(region).filterDate('2018-10-01','2018-12-31').select(['HH','HV','LIN']); thanks!